# Show 3 products in a Column & scroll Rows

Tags: php, html, css

I have products list,i have tried to align three products in a column and scroll towards right.how to shows only 9 ( 3 rows * 3 columns) products .this is my code.

```
<div style="border:solid 1px red;width:230px;overflow-x:scroll;">
  <h4>Items/Products</h4>
  <hr>
  <table border="0">    
    <?php $count =0;
    for($pr=0;$pr < count($items_list);$pr++){  ?>
      <?php if($count % 3 == 0) { ?> <tr> <?php } ?>
      <td style="border:solid 1px black;width:100px;height:40px;text-align:center">
        <?php echo $items_list[$pr]->category;?>     
      </td>
      <?php  if($count % 3 == 0) { ?> </tr> <?php } ?>
      <?php $count++; 
    } ?>
 </table>
</div>
```

I have tried exactly look like this [see here](http://postimg.org/image/eifr7azob/). How to change my code?

Comment: How to change your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        <div style="border:solid 1px red;width:430px;overflow-x:scroll;">
        <h4>Items/Products</h4>
        <hr>
        <table border="0">  
             <tr>
             <?php $count =1; //$countItems = count($items_list);
                         $countItems =11;
             for($pr=0;$pr < $countItems;$pr++){  ?>                     
                    <td style="border:solid 1px black;width:100px;height:40px;text-align:center"> <?php echo $pr;?>
                        <?php //echo $items_list[$pr]->category;?>
                    </td>
                    <?php if($count % 3 == 0) { ?> </tr><tr><?php } ?>
                <?php $count++; } ?>
         </table>
    </div>
```

**3 Rows x N columns**

```
    <div style="border:solid 1px red;width:430px;overflow-x:scroll;">
        <h4>Items/Products</h4>
        <hr>
        <table border="0">  
             <tr>
             <?php $count =1; 
             //$items_list_count = count($items_list);
             $items_list_count =  25;
             $Rows = 3;              
             $coulmns =@ceil($items_list_count/$Rows);               
             for($pr=0;$pr < $items_list_count;$pr++){  ?>                   
                    <td style="border:solid 1px black;width:100px;height:40px;text-align:center">
                        <?php //echo $items_list[$pr]->category;?> <?php echo $pr;?>
                    </td>
                    <?php if($count % $coulmns == 0) { ?> </tr><tr><?php } ?>
                <?php $count++; } ?>
         </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you check  `echo $countItems = count($items_list);` how many count ?

Comment: total count items are 11

Comment: 3 rows only coming,column increasing .i tried only 3 columns .

Comment: Copy my code and run it again! i have updated my code!

Comment: 4 rows coming,i expected only 3 rows and multiple columns

Comment: You want only 3 rows only, n columns right ? 3 x N ?

Comment: you are right 3 rows  and multiple columns .look like this http://postimg.org/image/eifr7azob/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax Pagination or Jquery Scolling to become (http://postimg.org/image/eifr7azob/)